# apt upgrade systemd fails, users and groups already exist

Tags: apt, server, systemd, adduser

If I try to upgrade systemd via `apt update && apt upgrade`, the systemd portion indicates the users and groups already exist so it exits.
edit: this is on 16.04 server

```
Setting up systemd (229-4ubuntu21.1) ...
addgroup: The group `systemd-journal' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
adduser: The user `systemd-timesync' already exists. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The only way through so far is to remove the groups and users, then run `apt upgrade` again.

I had to move my system users into a non-common range due to a programming making assumptions that the company's "Branch 01" users will have uids in the 100 range. So, adduser.conf shows the following for system accounts:

```
FIRST_SYSTEM_UID=50100
LAST_SYSTEM_UID=59999

FIRST_SYSTEM_GID=50100
LAST_SYSTEM_GID=59999
```

`/etc/passwd` shows these users in those ranges:

```
systemd-timesync:x:50031:50102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:50032:50103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:50033:50104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:50034:50105:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
```

As does `/etc/group`:

```
systemd-journal:x:50118:
systemd-timesync:x:50102:
systemd-network:x:50103:
systemd-resolve:x:50104:
systemd-bus-proxy:x:50105:
```

I think I only need to remove systemd-journal from /etc/group though... at least with the upgrades I've attempted so far

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can't read. The UIDs in /etc/passwd aren't within the range specified in adduser.conf
So, I fixed it by adjusting adduser.conf to encompass UIDs 50000-59999.

My own fault.